# Using signed certificates with shellinabox

Tags: apache-http-server, ssl, certificate

I currently have a web server running Apache. This server hosts a website (foo.com), and is configured to use a signed RSA certificate for https connections. The Apache configuration for the site looks something like this:

```
SSLEngine On
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/foo_site/foo_com.ca-bundle
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/foo_site/foo_com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/foo_site/foo.com-key.pem
```

I have installed [shellinabox](https://code.google.com/archive/p/shellinabox/), started it up, and it works well with the self-signed certificates it auto-generated (in /var/lib/shellinabox/).

I would like to configure it to use the same certificates that my website foo.com uses (since it's accessed through the same domain). However, I cannot seem to figure out how to make it use them instead of using its own self-signed certificates. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I made it localhost-only access, then set up a reverse proxy to it in the Apache config. Works like a charm!